# Can I distribute iOS open source code to bypass the app store?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, open-source, app-store

I am not talking about beta testing using https://testflightapp.com/ or even the limited distribution of beta apps allowed by Apple in general.

I know that in order to install "your own" apps for testing, you have to have an Apple Developer account for $100/year.

For people that have this, what is preventing legal distribution of the source code so that an open source app can be distributed, built, installed, tested and run on their own devices by end users?

I am well aware of the fact that this distribution model precludes a great majority of end users. This aside, it seems it would be an effective way to bypass Apple's restrictions.

If the process, for the end user, of registering the Apple Developer key, building and installing an app could be streamlined (likely by a Mac app), then the only barrier would be the yearly Apple Developer fee.

If there are compelling reasons to do this (e.g. high quality apps that likely break App Store policies or whose license precludes App Store distribution, like VLC or a version of Chrome that uses a native V8 javascript implementation and its own rendering engine, or many awesome apps that are available only on Cydia [and don't *require* a jailbroken device to function] or haven't been built at all), I think that some people might start to make that leap.

As far as I know, Apple would have no way to identify which users (either source distributors or end users) would be engaged in this activity. Nor do I think that this would violate any Apple policies (off hand, I haven't read the fine print, I suppose this could be problematic).

What am I missing? Why hasn't this been done yet?

Comment: One question though...Then how will people make money..?

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava: set up a system that lets you only download the source code if you have paid through systems like PayPal.

Comment: Most people work hard on their source code and don't want to show it to everyone.

Comment: @borrrden any harder than the people who wrote Firefox or Chrome or the multitude of open source software available? That's not a valid reason.

Comment: The examples I gave are both open source (VLC and Chrome [well, chromium]) and hampered only by app store policies. There are plenty of good reasons to provide source code freely. Perhaps other uses might be so that a developer can provide a free, albeit difficult to use, not for everyone, option while continuing to use the App Store to generate revenue from most users. Would Sparrow users be so upset today (in light of their acquisition by Google) had its developers open sourced the code? Open source code does not mean that the binary can't be sold.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I'm not comparing.  Your point is irrelevant.  What to do with source is entirely up to whomever wrote it.

Comment: It is now possible to install open-source apps using Xcode 7 for free (without having to pay the developer fee). As mentioned on the Apple Xcode site and with examples like: http://bouk.co/blog/sideload-iphone/

Answer (score 0):

While the idea is smart, people don't want to go through this effort. You can't download apps from the App Store on your device anymore (well, you can, but you'd have to pay if it's paid). People choose Apple for its simplicity, doing it this way complicates the whole process a lot.

The App Store also protects: it is safe to assume that everything in the App Store does not harm one's device.

And, of course, if this really becomes a problem, Apple simply changes its policy (within x days of creating your account, you have to submit something to the App Store or your account is suspended).

Comment: How could they enforce this policy if they couldn't identify who was violating it?

Comment: Protection is a double edged sword... As for the difficulty, I am proposing building a process/mac app to streamline it. Click a link on the app you want to install from the web browser, the source is downloaded, built and installed on your device. One click. Yes, the setup would involve installing the app, getting registered with the Apple Developer program and installing the key. Still, making it easy is exactly want I want to do.

Comment: Presumably then, you're talking about building an iTunes equivalent, which, instead of just downloading a build app, would download the source instead. To me it seems that the hardest part would be coming up with a standard structure for the app so that the build always works. Not every developer actually has the xcode projects included in their source. So somehow the deliverables would have to be something like a zip with xcode projects included, so all you would do is call xcodebuild -workspace AppName after unzipping.

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem with this. Thousands of people do this (including myself) when they release examples of their frameworks on github. For example, the AFNetworking (https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) repository has a working application distributed in it that you need a developer account to compile and run. If you had an app that violated the App Stores policies, releasing the source code would allow developer to run it.

Comment: Yes, exactly what I knew was being done in ad-hoc ways. Lets find a way to simplify the process for end users. Apple might even "turn the other cheek" as they benefit from the $100/yr accounts too.

Comment: If there was a single place for this, that got some credibility and that users showed interest in, like Cydia is for jailbroken devices, then I bet a lot of larger apps would be interested in it.